# Notes Plus app not working

Tags: ipod.app

for some reason the toolbar that is normally at the top of my notes plus app is at the bottom and the shade that you pull up so your palm doesn't Touch the glass is on the top. What can I do to straighten this out?

Answer (score 1):

If your tool bar appears across the bottom of your "notes plus" app ,simply tap the picture of the wrench  down in the right-hand corner.Several pictures of hands showing ways to hold your stylus will appear. You simply choose one and a bar will then return to the top.