# Already found answer to iPad app?

Tags: ipad, applications

after continuing to look around I found the answer to my problem with the notes plus app. It told you what to do to fix it. I'm sorry I troubled anyone with the question.

Comment: This was the Question... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153544/notes-plus-app-not-working